# Python stream Windows 10 session to remote server

Tags: python, linux, windows, web, stream

I have a couple of Windows machines, and I would like to have control over those machines by having a live stream from each machine on my web server.

Is there any way to do that via Python script that would be deployed on the those Windows machines?

I would like to send those stream to my Linux/Ubuntu server, and view those streams on that web server.

Comment: Are you planning to code this yourself or are you looking tool / software?

Comment: @JamesZ thank you for the reply! Well I am open for any solution, as long as I can watch those sessions in real time.